# width in pixels of a character in Xcode

Tags: ios

I want to write a character to an iPad screen beginning at any pixel.  The problem I'm having is determining the width of the last character so that I can position the next character.  This is the code I have.

```
NSString *mathText = @"#h23#D45 73#";
//const char *mathTextStr = "#F23#D45   73#";
UIFont * font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Times" size:15];
CGContextSetTextPosition( myContext, 100, 100 );
for (int i = 0; i < mathText.length; i++) {
    len = 1;
    NSString *subString = [mathText substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
    const char *oneChar = [subString UTF8String];
    //CGContextShowTextAtPoint(myContext, x, y,oneChar , 1);
    CGContextShowText(myContext, oneChar, 1);
    CGSize charWidth = [subString sizeWithFont:font];

    x=x+charWidth.width+3;
     NSLog(@"x coordinate = %f", x);
    CGContextSetTextPosition( myContext, x, y );
    }
```

The problem is the characters seems to be with CGSize charWidth.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: This is a problem for Core Text. The width of "the last character" is not a meaningful question. You need the bounds of the last glyph, which may be different depending on many factors. Can you explain the larger problem you're trying to solve? Laying out characters one at a time will often not give good results, because it ignores character->glyph translations.

Comment: That said, the above code looks like it would probably lay something out reasonably close to what you'd expect. What is the problem you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

create a category for UILabel with this function:

```
-(CGSize)expectedLabelSize{
    return [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font
                 constrainedToSize:self.frame.size
                     lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode];
}
```

call it like: [myLabel expectedLabelSize];

Comment: I'm trying to create a math app (for instance, to add fractions) and I want to be able to display, say, 3/4 + 5/6, as a stacked fraction rather than slash fraction as shown in this reply.  To do do, I need to write to specific parts of the screen.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1320952 Not something that iOS does well, though there might be some tricks you can pull off with annotated strings.